# Determine Unix or Windows EOL character

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am reading a file and interested in knowing the operating system that generated the file. It can be either Windows or Unix. I am trying to determine the operating system by reading end of line character. I am facing difficulty in getting the character at end of line. I tried the following code but it always returns -2 irrespective of the operating system (which is correct as per the documentation). Thanks for your help.

```
def var cLog as char init "myfile.log".

input from value (cLog).
seek input to end.

readkey.
message lastkey.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes there really is a end of line in the file so perhaps not a perfect solution (on the other hand - if there isn't - how can you tell).

I skip the `SEEK` part. Instead i just check for the pattern in the file.

Writing CHR(13) + CHR(10) is similar to what could be written as `\r\n`. This can also be escaped `~r~n` in Progress ABL (see below).

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cFile AS LONGCHAR NO-UNDO.

COPY-LOB FROM FILE "c:\temp\file.txt" TO cFile.

IF cFile MATCHES "*" + CHR(13) + CHR(10) + "*" THEN DO:
    MESSAGE "Likely a Windows-file" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
END.
ELSE IF cFile MATCHES "*" + CHR(13) + "*" THEN DO:
    MESSAGE "Likely a Mac file" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
END.    
ELSE IF cFile MATCHES "*" + CHR(10) + "*" THEN DO:
    MESSAGE "Likely a Linux-file" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
END.    
ELSE DO:
    MESSAGE "I cannot tell what file this is" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
END.
```

With escaped characters

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cFile AS LONGCHAR NO-UNDO.

COPY-LOB FROM FILE "c:\temp\file.txt" TO cFile.

IF cFile MATCHES "*~r~n*" THEN DO:
    MESSAGE "Likely a Windows-file" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
END.
ELSE IF cFile MATCHES "*~r*" THEN DO:
    MESSAGE "Likely a Mac file" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
END.    
ELSE IF cFile MATCHES "*~n*" THEN DO:
    MESSAGE "Likely a Linux-file" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
END.    
ELSE DO:
    MESSAGE "I cannot tell what file this is" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
END.
```